# Jenkins Windows slave gives Unexpected Error with JNLP start

Tags: windows, jenkins, jnlp, slave

I have a Jenkins server running happily on a Windows server. I need to connect 2 other windows servers as slaves.

One connects in fine (start using JNLP, then installed as a Windows service).

The other fails to connect using JNLP. Whether I use the Launch button or the javaws command line it fails with 'Unexpected Error - Unable to launch Slave Agent for {node}'. If I start the slave using the headless command line it works, so I suspect it's not networking/firewall related.

I'd like to get the JNLP launch working so I can install it as a Windows service.

Other notes:

- the Jenkins URL is set OK
- we're using Matrix security, but anonymous has Slave/Connect

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Hey, are you still having issue? I'm running into virtually the same issue. (except that headless won't run - "invalid/corrupt jar" :(

Comment: Yes, still setting the issue. It's not on a server that's a high priority so I haven't pursued it any more, but the issue hasn't been resolved, unfortunately.